# Doctrine Left join with limit

Tags: doctrine, left-join, limit

I made this request for get all brands and all items of theses brand with leftJoin :

```
$brands = Doctrine_Query::create()
->from('Brand b')
->leftJoin('b.Item i')
->fetchArray();
```

But I want to get only 10 items of each brand, how can I put the limit on Item leftJoin ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use subquery like this:

```
->leftJoin('b.Item i WITH i.id IN (SELECT i2.id FROM Item i2 WHERE i2.brand_id=b.id LIMIT 10)')
```

I didn't test this but it should work.

Comment: not sure LIMIT is valid DQL

Comment: You cannot use LIMIT in a subquery in DQL

Answer (score 1):

I know it's late but this actually scored nr 1 on my google search and is unanswered:
[Limiting a doctrine query with a fetch-joined collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620771/limiting-a-doctrine-query-with-a-fetch-joined-collection) suggests using Paginaror object

Here is an example:

My code has Sources that contain rss links and Articles that are articles from the rss feed. So in this example I'll get one Source and all it's articles.

```
        // get the articles (latest first) from source 743
        $q=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()
          ->createQuery('select s, a from MyCompanyRssBundle:Source s 
          join s.Articles a 
          where s.id = :id 
          order by a.id desc')
          ->setParameter('id',743);
        $q->setMaxResults(1);  // this limits Articles to be only 1
                               // when using $q->getResult();
        $sources=new Paginator($q, $fetchJoin = true);
        $sources=$sources->getIterator();
//      $sources=$q->getResult();
        var_dump($sources[0]->getArticles());
```

Comment: He asked how to get 10 items per brand rather than paginate brands.