# Doctrine 2 proxy loading and array result

Tags: join, doctrine-orm, lazy-loading, dql

...

Hi! with Doctrine 2.3, I'm trying to fetch, as an array, a list of users and their groups (for a change :) ).

So I have defined the user class like this:

```
/**
 * @Entity
 **/
class User {
    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Group")
     * @var Group[]
     **/
    protected $groups;

    ...
}
```

And the group class:

```
/**
 * @Entity
 **/
class Goup {
    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="User)
     * @var User[]
     **/
    protected $users;

    ...
}
```

Then I have 10'000 users and 100 groups, and each users can have several groups. I would like to retrieve, for read-only, the first 200 users with their groups.

How can I achieve this using an array hydratation? Is it possible?

I tried that:

```
$query = new \Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder($em);
$query
    ->select('u, g')
    ->from('User', 'u')
    ->leftJoin('Group', 'g')
    ->setFirstResult(0)
    ->setMaxResults(200)
    ->getQuery()
    ->getArrayResult();
```

But I don't get 200 users. Because of the join, I get let's say 40 or 50 users (which is normal, since the limit of 200 take groups into consideration). I know that with lazy (or eager?) load and proxies, I can defer the load for groups, but here I have an array, so I can't call any method.

Is there an annotation to add somewhere, or something to configure to the QueryBuilder, or the Query?

Many thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is described in the yellow note box here: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#first-and-max-result-items-dql-query-only

It's possible when you use the Doctrine Paginator instead of the getArrayResult(). You can read how to use the Paginator here: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/tutorials/pagination.html

This is a related question: [Limiting a doctrine query with a fetch-joined collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620771/limiting-a-doctrine-query-with-a-fetch-joined-collection)

Comment: Ok, so there's no "magic" way of limiting the resultset. Like a type of hydratation which should say "limit on from, then select all with these ids and then hydrate array". I'll give a try with the paginator, thanks!