# Doctrine MaxResults and Subentities

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine-query

I have a query look like this:

```
$limit = 3;    

$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('media')
      ->leftJoin('media.file', 'file')
      ->leftJoin('file.meta', 'fileMeta')
      ->addSelect('file')
      ->addSelect('fileMeta');

$qb->setMaxResults($limit);
```

The limit of the setMaxResults function impact also the Joins and so I don't get all meta of the file. What is the common way to handle a limit only on the main entity?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Limiting a doctrine query with a fetch-joined collection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620771/limiting-a-doctrine-query-with-a-fetch-joined-collection)

Comment: thank you it works with the paginator