# Long query time

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine, entity, dql

I have a query to post last 10 tv show episodes by sorting it by date (from newest to oldest) like this:

```
return $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery('SELECT t FROM AppBundle:TvShow t JOIN t.episodes e ORDER BY e.date DESC')->setFirstResult(0)->setMaxResults(10)->getResult();
```

It returns only 9 nine episode. We have similar queries in same page too, they are working fine. When i setMaxResults to (11) just then it returns 10 episodes.

Another issue related with this query is: it takes too long compared to other similar queries. (about 200ms)

What do you suggest for me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your actual question?  And is `t` a column in one of the tables or do you mean `t.*`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff t is a class (table). it is used to get all tv shows. i am using Symfony2 and Doctrine i don't know if it helps. My questions are: why it returns only nine episodes instead of ten?? and why does it take too long?

Comment: have you tried to create indexes for your mysql table ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Limiting a doctrine query with a fetch-joined collection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620771/limiting-a-doctrine-query-with-a-fetch-joined-collection)

Answer (score 1):

Like in Richard answer - wrong result with `setMaxResults` and `fetch-joined collection` is doctrine normal behaviour.

To make it works you can use Doctrine Pagination (from Doctrine 2.2) (docs: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/tutorials/pagination.html)

Example usage:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\Paginator;

$query->setMaxResults($limit);
$query->setFirstResult($offset);
$results = new Paginator($query, $fetchJoin = true);
```

Long query time looks like a topic for another question.

Answer (score 0):

Straight from the documentation:

If your query contains a fetch-joined collection specifying the result limit methods are not working as you would expect. Set Max Results restricts the number of database result rows, however in the case of fetch-joined collections one root entity might appear in many rows, effectively hydrating less than the specified number of results.

https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/