# Doctrine : wrong number of results when using left join on collection

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

In my application there is a `Case` entity that has a collection of `Operator` entities.

When I execute this request :

```
$this->createQueryBuilder('c')
    ->leftJoin('c.operators', 'od') // d -> one-to-many -> operator
    ->setMaxResults(100)
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult()
;
```

I get only 71 result (suppose that are `Cases` without any `Operator`).

Hydrating to array works well when there is no selection:

```
$this->createQueryBuilder('c')
    ->select('c, od') // notice select here which yields to 71 results (without it I get 100 results)
    ->leftJoin('c.operators', 'od')
    ->setMaxResults(100)
    ->getQuery()
    ->getArrayResult()
;
```

The things get really confusing as the real SQL obtained with `->getSQL()` returns 100 results in both cases.

Anyone can help ?

---

UPDATE

Actually I have precicely 100 results in the result set. These results are `Cases` combined with `Operators`. When `Dossier` in the result set has multiple `Operators` when this `Dossier` enters multiple times to the result set. Doctrine automatically shrinks this result set of 100 lines to the array of 71 unique `Cases`.

Comment: I think you should select from operators and then join (or "left join") the case (not the other way around). Did you try that?

Comment: What does your database query log have in both cases?

Comment: There is an important update in the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Limiting a doctrine query with a fetch-joined collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620771/limiting-a-doctrine-query-with-a-fetch-joined-collection)

Comment: There is nothing to do with Doctrine. Take a look on https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle, it will do this job for you (using additional query).