# How to limits results by main entity, not with childrens?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony3.x

How to limits results by main entity, not with childrens?

If I do:

```
    $queryBuilder = $em->createQueryBuilder();

    $queryBuilder->select('n, c');
    $queryBuilder->from('AppBundle:News', 'n');
    $queryBuilder->leftJoin('n.comments', 'c');
    $queryBuilder->setMaxResults(3);

    $results = $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();
```

And first News has for example 3 comments, then results return me only one record News. If I don't have comments or if I remove leftJoin, then this is working well.

Comment: in query builder you can't or remove left join on comments and lazy load your comments data but this would produce N+1 queries issue

Comment: Misunderstood the question on my first duplicate flag, however still a duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620771/limiting-a-doctrine-query-with-a-fetch-joined-collection offers a solution.

Answer (score -1):

You are using the wrong variable for your results.

You are using `$queryBuilder` to prepare your statement:

```
$queryBuilder = $em->createQueryBuilder();
```

But taking `$qb` to get your result;

```
$results = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake only on stackoverflow.

Answer (score -1):

Doctrine can behave unexpectedly with joins, multiple wheres and pagination.

The recommended way is to use the Paginator, and not directly call getResults.
The paginator handles the grouping of the results to the main entity.

Edit: to supply some sample code:

```
<?php
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\Paginator;

$dql = "SELECT p, c FROM BlogPost p JOIN p.comments c";
$query = $entityManager->createQuery($dql)
                       ->setFirstResult(0)
                       ->setMaxResults(100);

$paginator = new Paginator($query, $fetchJoinCollection = true);

$c = count($paginator);
foreach ($paginator as $post) {
    echo $post->getHeadline() . "\n";
}
```

https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/tutorials/pagination.html